# Kubernetes identify if deployment or scale up

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I do some action on the start of the pod after deployment. But dont want to do it for scale up . Is there a way to identify when a pod is create if it is a new deployment or a scale up/recreate event

Comment: Could you please give some more insight on "some action". Regarding a way to identify pods that are created after scale up, you may run `kubectl get events`

Comment: I don't think those two cases are distinguishable (or really distinct).  If a deployment has 3 pod replicas, do you want all three pods to run the first time you create the deployment?

Comment: So let me give a scenario. I have DB updates as part of startup script for the pod. When the pod starts it updates DB(Check is there if the updates are already applied or not). But I dont want to execute this steps when I scale up. So want to put a check in the pod startup script to check if the steps are to be executed ot not.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run some db script on the first available pod after the deployment.

Will it work for you if you follow the following steps during the deployment creation:

```
$ kubectl apply -f app-deployment.yml

// This will give some time for the pod to start.
$ WAIT_BEFORE_DATABASE_SETUP="${WAIT_BEFORE_DATABASE_SETUP-120}"
$ sleep $WAIT_BEFORE_DATABASE_SETUP 

// Pick any one pod which is in Running State
$ APP_POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | grep <deployment-name> | head -1)

$ kubectl exec -it $APP_POD_NAME -- bash -c "/scripts/run_db_updates.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to update a flag in your DB and have your script check against the value of that flag.